# How to find a substring

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex

Given a text file containing a string, I would find some specific substrings/sequences inside this string.

**Bison file .y**    (Declaration+Rules)

```
%token <cval> AMINO 
%token STARTCODON STOPCODON
%type <cval> seq

%%
series: STARTCODON seq STOPCODON {printf("%s", $2);}
seq: AMINO
         | seq AMINO
         ;
%%
```

Here I want to print every sequence between `STARTCODON` and `STOPCODON`

**Flex file .l** (Rules)

```
    %%
    ("ATG")+ {return STARTCODON;}
    ("TAA"|"TAG"|"TGA")+ {return STOPCODON;}

    ("GCT"|"GCC"|"GCA"|"GCG")+ {yylval.cval = 'A';
                           return AMINO;}
    ("CGT"|"CGC"|"CGA"|"CGG"|"AGA"|"AGG")+ {yylval.cval = 'R';
                           return AMINO;}
     .
     .
     .

     [ \t]+                  /*ignore whitespace*/
     \n                      /*ignore end of line*/
     . {printf("-");}
     %%
```

When I run the code I get only the output of the rule `. {printf("-");}`.

I am new `Flex/Bison`, I suspect that:

- The `bison` rule `series: STARTCODON seq STOPCODON {printf("%s", $2);}` is not correct.
- `Flex` doesn't subdivide correctly the entire string into tokens of 3 characters.

**EDIT:**

(Example) **Input file:** *DnaSequence.txt*:

Input string:`cccATGAATTATTAGzzz`, where lower characters (`ccc`, `zzz`) produce the (right) output `-`, `ATG` is the `STARTCODON`, `AATTAT` is the sequence of two `AMINO` (*AAT* *TAT*), and `TAG` is the `STOPCODON`.

This input string produces the (wrong) output `---`.

**EDIT:**

Following the suggestions of @JohnBollinger I have added `<<EOF>> {return ENDTXT;}` in the Flex file, and the rule `finalseries: series ENDTXT;` in the Bison file.

Now it's returning the `yyerror`'s error message, indicating a parsing error.
I suppose that we need a `STARTTXT` token, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: You declare a type for non-terminal symbol `seq`, and you use it, but you do not present a production for it.  Is this supposed to be the same thing as `sequenza`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I have edited the post now.

Comment: Your question seems promising, but it the code presented is not quite enough for a [mcve], and you do not present example input or corresponding expected output.  If you present a *bona fide* MCVE then I think we can help you.

Comment: @DavisHerring, Flex accepts quoted strings as patterns for literals.  It's a bit odd to use them in a situation like this, where they are not needed, but I don't think that's the problem if Flex is indeed in use.

Comment: You have a conflict between your flex & bison files in terms of what `YYSTYPE` is - the bison is using `cval` as a string, but flex is using it to store a single `char`

Comment: @ChrisTurner How could I fix this issue?

Comment: By defining it the once in a header file and including that file in the bison and flex files.

Comment: Or better yet, use the `%union` directive in the bison file and have it generate the header for use by flex.

Comment: @ChrisTurner I have used `%union {
    char cval;
}` in the `bison` file, but I get the same wrong output.

Comment: By "wrong output" you mean it's crashing with a segfault? Because I can't see how it won't with the code as is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am new Flex/Bison, I suspect that:
>
> - The bison rule series: STARTCODON seq STOPCODON {printf("%s", $2);} is not correct.

The rule is syntactically acceptable.  It would be semantically correct if the value of token 2 were a C string, in which case it would cause that value to be printed to the standard output, but your Flex file appears to assume that type `<cval>` is `char`, which is *not* a C string, nor directly convertible to one.

> - Flex doesn't subdivide correctly the entire string into tokens of 3 characters.

Your Flex input looks OK to me, actually.  And the example input / output you present indicates that Flex is indeed recognizing all your triplets from `ATG` to `TAG`, else the rule for `.` would be triggered more than three times.

---

The datatype problem is a detail that you'll need to sort out, but the *main* problem is that your production for `seq` does not set its semantic value.  How that results in (seemingly) nothing being printed when the `series` production is used for a reduction depends on details that you have not disclosed, and probably involves undefined behavior.

If `<cval>` were declared as a string (`char *`), and if your lexer set its values as strings rather than as characters, then setting the semantic value might look something like this:

```
seq: AMINO { $$ = calloc(MAX_AMINO_ACIDS + 1, 1); /* check for allocation failure ... */
             strcpy($$, $1); }
         | seq AMINO { $$ = $1; strcat($$, $2); }
         ;
```

You might consider sticking with `char` as the type for the semantic value of `AMINO`, and defining `seq` to have a different type (i.e. `char *`).  That way, your changes could be restricted to the grammar file.  That would, however, call for a different implementation of the semantic actions in the production for `seq`.

---

Finally, note that although you say

> Here I want to print every sequence between STARTCODON and STOPCODON

your grammar, as presented, has `series` as its start symbol.  Thus, once it reduces the token sequence to a `series`, it expects to be done.  If additional tokens follow (say those of another `series`) then that would be erroneous.  If that's something you need to support then you'll need a higher-level start symbol representing a sequence of multiple `series`.

Comment: By default if you don't specify anything you get `$$ = $1` so `seq` will take the first `AMINO` value parsed. Which still isn't a string, so the code has to be crashing when it tries printing it out.

Comment: Yes, @ChrisTurner, the default semantic-value assignment is `$$ = $1`.  This is relevant and useful to know, but I think the (probable) crash in the original code is more fundamentally a function of the mismatched datatypes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have followed your suggestions about the first two issues, and now the script works fine. About the last point, I haven't found a solution and I'm getting the `yyerror`'s parsing error message, as written in the new "edit" above.

Comment: @Simone, my final comment is about the possibility that the input will contain multiple distinct series.  It remains unclear to me whether that is in fact an issue for you, but if it is, then the addition to your grammar that you describe is altogether the wrong thing.  In that case, you need a production with which you can combine multiple `series` symbols into a single `multi_series` (or whatever else you would like to name it).